GUI Screen Issues on Rocky Linux 9.4 with NVIDIA Driver Installation
On Rocky Linux 9.4, there is an issue where the GUI screen does not appear after installing the NVIDIA driver. The server is equipped with four PCIE type A100 GPUs.
The driver version is 555.42.06, and the installation method is as follows:
sudo dnf install kernel-devel-$(uname -r) kernel-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo rpm --install cuda-repo-rhel9-12-5-local-12.5.1_555.42.06-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo dnf module install nvidia-driver:latest-dkms

Edit the following file:
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf

blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0

Then, run:
sudo dracut --force
sudo reboot

After rebooting, the screen remains black after boot. However, switching to CLI mode using ctrl + alt + F2 on the KVM provides a functional CLI screen. Running nvidia-smi indicates that the GPU driver is installed correctly.
I am looking for a solution to get the GUI screen working on Rocky Linux.
